# Sitecore or Unicorn auto sync items locally during night on my dev machine?

Tags: synchronization, sitecore, unicorn, auto

I have a problem with my branch being clean when I leave work, and when I return the next morning I have a list of 50 Sitecore items that are updated. It is only a `Date Last Syncronized` value that have been updated, but I am losing my mind over this, do there exist a feature that lets you auto sync locally during the night or in a specific time span?

[image: Example Unicorn file]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Date last synchronized` is not a standard Sitecore or Unicorn field. It looks like your solution has a custom job that runs on schedule and updates items in the folder `/sitecore/content/Portals/Reference data/`. When an item is updated and this item is located in a folder configured for Unicorn serialization, the Unicorn event handler will trigger serialization for this item and the corresponding `.yml` file will update automatically.

In order to find the job, check your Sitecore logs around the time of item update, check Sitecore schedulers and any custom modules or scheduling tools you may have on the website.

Another thing to consider is excluding this folder from Unicorn serialization. If items in this folder are synced with another system on a regular basis, then do you need them to be committed in the code repository and deployed to other environments?